# How do I rename a field name of a table?

Tags: database

I need to rename one of my fields in a table via a .install file. How can I to do this ?

**Let us consider I have a table called "register" and field name called "fname". Now I need to change the field name "fname" to "name". How can I do this using a .install file?**

We can add a field for a table using the below syntax :

```
db_add_field($ret, 'table_name', 'field_name', array('type' => 'varchar',
             'length' => 255, 'not null' => TRUE,));
```

What is the syntax for doing a field rename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [db_change_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_change_field/7).

Under the parameter section:

> $field Name of the field to change.
>
> $field_new New name for the field (set to the same as $field if you
>   don't want to change the name).